# How to use FileProvider with created PFD in Download folder in SDK Q and Above

Tags: java, android, mediastore, android-fileprovider

Recently I've updated an app to target SDK 30 and adapted the way to create and store a PDF with Mediastore. For create and store I use this piece of code:

```
     @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
    @NonNull
    private Uri savePDFFile(@NonNull final Context context, @NonNull byte[] in,
                            @NonNull final String mimeType,
                            @NonNull final String displayName, @Nullable final String subFolder) throws IOException {
        String relativeLocation = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS;

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(subFolder)) {
            relativeLocation += File.separator + subFolder;
        }

        final ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, displayName);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, mimeType);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        OutputStream stream = null;
        Uri uri = null;

        try {
            final Uri contentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");
            uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd;
            try {
                assert uri != null;
                pfd = context.getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "w");
                assert pfd != null;
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(pfd.getFileDescriptor());

                out.write(in);

                out.close();

                pfd.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            contentValues.clear();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0);
            context.getContentResolver().update(uri, contentValues, null, null);
            stream = resolver.openOutputStream(uri);
            if (stream == null) {
                throw new IOException("Failed to get output stream.");
            }
            return uri;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Don't leave an orphan entry in the MediaStore
            resolver.delete(uri, null, null);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (stream != null) {
                stream.close();
                  renderPDF(this.fileName, this.fileType);
            }
        }
    }
```

The PDf is stored in /storage/emulated/0/Download and once is saved I want to render it by intent

```
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
        File file = new File(path.toString() + "/" + fileName + "." + filetype);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,  getPackageName() + ".provider",file), "application/pdf");
```

My provider_paths.xml is setted like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external"
        path="Download/" />
    <external-files-path
        name="external_files"
        path="Download/" />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="Download/" />
</paths>
```

At this point  when you download a pdf shows the pdf reader you want to select and when you choose one shows a message error saying the path is too long?!?(discarded) or if is the Google Drive Pdf Reader shows for a millisecond a blank screen and back again to the app.

How is the proper way to retrieve the pdf file and launch the intent with FileProvider?
I think the problem is in the FileProvider at this point but I don't know how...

```
        intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,  getPackageName() + ".provider",file), "application/pdf");
```

Comment: You do not need to mess around with file paths and FileProvider to get an uri. You already have an uri: `uri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`. Use it!

Comment: Success!!! Thank you @blackapps using the uri directly in: intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");  was the solution.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer.